# IE8 calls full URL

Tags: javascript

We have this issue where IE8 calls full url instead of the id. To better understand, please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/8khES/).

FF:

```
<a target="_self" "="" onclick="DoRow( &quot;UBSPSYALAN05&quot;);return false;" href="#" data-original-title="3 applications&lt;br&gt;in total." data-placement="top" class="total-applications">3 applications no decision.</a>
```

IE 8:

```
<a class="total-applications" onclick="DoRow( "HTTPS://DOMAIN.UK/URD/SITS.URD/RUN/UBALINSING05");return false;" href="https://domain.uk/urd/sits.urd/run/SIW_YMHD.start_url?zuJ7uWeJUhh8%1Be=zazG=R%5F3I%5Fn1hF%15%1B%241b=qXLF=FSg%15%1B6VsO8j6BC=h%1B4be=taq%5F6BmP%1B5vw=PuVx26ps%1BCWu=MRh%1BzUy=Tpt0sn5%1B8iG=xqqqvixjzWhAeJ67IRJEJwyCSayJfgsl#" target="_self" data-original-title="1 applications<br>in total." data-placement="top" ?="">
```

Works in FF and not in IE8.

Comment: Because the code for IE8 is actually different than that used in FF? Figure out why that is.

Comment: Where does `totalUrl` come from?

Comment: Can you explain where you define totalUrl?

Comment: `ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.1.` and corresponding `id`s are invalid in IE8, also `data-*` attributes are not supported.

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle for you to see the full code. You should see the related functions...http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/8khES/  Thanks

Comment: @19eggs - For better visibility, can you add the link [to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17431217/edit)?

Comment: The link for IE8 doesn't have any text or a closing tag in your fiddle. Also the onclick handler is in double quotes but the string you're sending to DoRow is also in double-quotes. Try wrapping that string in single quotes and completing the <a> tag.

Comment: @JoelAnair I have update the line..I think I had put the wrong code.

Comment: Dear all, looks like we needed to replace totalUrl with id.
 var totalapplications = '<a href="#"  class="total-applications" data-placement="top" data-original-title="' + totalNumber + ' applications<br>in total." onclick="'+DoRow+'( &quot;' + totalUrl.toUpperCase() + '&quot;);' + 'return false;" " target="_self" >' + totalNumber + ' applications no decision.</a>' ;

TO-->>

onclick="'+DoRow+'( &quot;' + id + '&quot;);'  Thanks for all the help and suggestion.